# How to commit changed path to the file

Tags: git

I made changes to my project src folder. 
Here is how the path looked: `src/program/Main.java`
How it is now: `src/**course**/program/Main.java`.

When I try to commit changes to my remote repository, git shows me the following error:

> [rejected]        master -> dev (non-fast-forward) error: failed to
>   push some refs to 'git@git...:user/Project'

How can the changes in the path be applied to the remote repository?

Comment: Not sure the `java` tag is appropriate here.

Comment: There are a looooot of results if you google "non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refs to". Try to help yourself first.

Comment: `[rejected] master -> dev` try to commit changes on the same branch then push it

Answer (score 0):

First, perform a `git pull origin YOUR_BRANCH_NAME` prior to pushing. This should simply retrieve the remote repo updates and merge them with your local work.